# Apache Spark on EC2. Environment Variable problems. Mac OSX

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, apache-spark

I am following the tutorial found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/ec2-scripts.html) to get a Spark Cluster up and running. I am using a Mac OS 10.9. I am new to using a Mac. When attempting to launch the cluster I get an error:

> ERROR: The environment variable AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID must be set

I don't fully understand environment variables etc. I thought I had created a .bash_profile in my home directory but it wasn't the case, as my home directory (~) is not where it should be. As such I located .profile and .bashrc & I know I need to edit one of them however, I can't. I consistently get `Access Denied`. I'm pretty stumped on what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your environment variables in bash like:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=accesskeyhere
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secretkeyhere
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! The program isn't working however it's due to a different error which I'll try to work out. However, if possible could you please tell me where this information is stored? It's not in `.bashrc` or `.profile`. I can't find a `.bash_profile` or a `launchd.conf` (all of which are suggested in other answers on Stackoverflow). Thanks again!

Comment: Those keys come from AWS when you create an EC2 account. If you're not using EC2 then that guide isn't relevant for you.

Comment: Apologies, I meant where are environment variables in general stored on my Mac. Obviously the `export....` makes changes, I'd just like to know where etc. Thank you again!